# Is it possible to open an .mp4 in fullscreen mode on iPad when video is referenced within an link?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, video

Basically I have a link `<a href="../video/link-to-video.mp4">Play</a>` in my mobile web app. I would like this video to open in fullscreen mode when on iPad but am unsure if this is possible? At the moment the video fills the available screen space but I actually have to physically click fullscreen. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept requests by implementing UIWebViewDelegate’s `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method. If you intercept a request whose URL ends with `.mp4`, you can return `NO` and spawn a MPMoviePlayerViewController and play the link in it. Otherwise you return `YES` to allow any other form of navigation in your web view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `<video>` element and set its size to 100% for width and height. I have not tested it.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp

Comment: hey, is it possible to do this though straight from within an a tag?

Comment: you will need some JS to do this.

Comment: can you advise the js that is required by any chance?